# How are the conditional expectation and conditional independence treated in tower property?

Tags: probability-theory, statistical-inference, conditional-expectation

I was going through a proof of a [theorem regarding U-Statistics (Large Sample Theory)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q1ydx7qfe9okyho/lec16.U_stats_contd.pdf?dl=0) and got stuck to figure out a particular step that includes conditional expectation and conditional independence.

> Theorem : When $\textrm{n}\geq \textrm{2m-1}$, the variance of a U-Statistic is $$\textrm{Var}_{F}[U_{n}] = \frac{1}{\binom{\textrm{n}}{\textrm{m}}}\sum_{\textrm{k}=1}^{\textrm{m}}\binom{\textrm{m}}{\textrm{k}} \binom{\textrm{n-m}}{\textrm{m-k}}\sigma_{\textrm{k}}^2 \ \ .$$ If $\sigma_{\textrm{1}}^2, \sigma_{\textrm{2}}^2,..., \sigma_{\textrm{m}}^2< \infty$, then $$\textrm{Var}_{F}[U_{n}] = \textrm{m}^2 \sigma_{1}^2\mathit{O}(\frac{1}{\textrm{n}})+\mathit{O}(\frac{1}{\textrm{n}^2}) \  \ .$$

My problem arises when the proof uses conditional expectation, tower rule and conditional independence while determining the $\mathbb{E}(\mathit{XY})$ term of the covariance.

The covariance is -

$$\textit{Cov}_{\ \textrm{F}}[\textit{g}(\textrm{Y}_{1}, \textrm{Y}_{2},..., \textrm{Y}_{m}).\textit{g}(\textrm{Y}_{1}, \textrm{Y}_{2},..., \textrm{Y}_{k},\textrm{Y}_{m+1},...,\textrm{Y}_{m+(m-k)}]$$
$$=\textit{E}_{\ \textrm{F}}[\textit{g}(\textrm{Y}_{1}, \textrm{Y}_{2},..., \textrm{Y}_{m}).\textit{g}(\textrm{Y}_{1}, \textrm{Y}_{2},..., \textrm{Y}_{k},\textrm{Y}_{m+1},...,\textrm{Y}_{m+(m-k)}] - \textit{E}_{\ \textrm{F}}[\textit{g}(\textrm{Y}_{1}, \textrm{Y}_{2},..., \textrm{Y}_{m})].\textit{E}_{\ \textrm{F}}[(\textrm{Y}_{1}, \textrm{Y}_{2},..., \textrm{Y}_{k},\textrm{Y}_{m+1},...,\textrm{Y}_{m+(m-k)}] $$

Now, for $1\leq k \leq m$,
$$\textit{E}_{\ \textrm{F}}[\ \textit{g}(\textrm{Y}_{1}, \textrm{Y}_{2},..., \textrm{Y}_{m}).\textit{g}(\textrm{Y}_{1}, \textrm{Y}_{2},..., \textrm{Y}_{k},\textrm{Y}_{m+1},...,\textrm{Y}_{m+(m-k)} \ ] \\ = \textit{E}_{ \textrm{F}}\{\textit{E}_{\ \textrm{F}}[\ \textit{g}(\textrm{Y}_{1}, \textrm{Y}_{2},..., \textrm{Y}_{m}).\textit{g}(\textrm{Y}_{1}, \textrm{Y}_{2},..., \textrm{Y}_{k},\textrm{Y}_{m+1},...,\textrm{Y}_{m+(m-k)}|\textrm{Y}_{1}, \textrm{Y}_{2},..., \textrm{Y}_{k}\ ]\} \longrightarrow \textrm{(i)} \\ =\textit{E}_{\ \textrm{F}}[\textit{E}_{\ \textrm{F}}[\ \textit{g}(\textrm{Y}_{1}, \textrm{Y}_{2},..., \textrm{Y}_{m})|\textrm{Y}_{1}, \textrm{Y}_{2},..., \textrm{Y}_{k} \ ].\textit{E}_{\ \textrm{F}}[\ \textit{g}(\textrm{Y}_{1}, \textrm{Y}_{2},..., \textrm{Y}_{k},\textrm{Y}_{m+1},...,\textrm{Y}_{m+(m-k)}|\textrm{Y}_{1}, \textrm{Y}_{2},..., \textrm{Y}_{k} \ ]] \longrightarrow \textrm{(ii)}\\ =\textit{E}_{\ \textrm{F}}[\textit{g}_{1}|\textrm{Y}].\textit{E}_{\ \textrm{F}}[\textit{g}_{2}|\textrm{Y}] \longrightarrow \textrm{(iii)}$$
where $\textit{g}[(\textrm{Y}_{1}, \textrm{Y}_{2},..., \textrm{Y}_{m})|\textrm{Y}_{1}, \textrm{Y}_{2},..., \textrm{Y}_{k}]=[\textit{g}_{1}|\textrm{Y}]$ and $\textit{g}[(\textrm{Y}_{1}, \textrm{Y}_{2},..., \textrm{Y}_{k},\textrm{Y}_{m+1},...,\textrm{Y}_{m+(m-k)})|\textrm{Y}_{1}, \textrm{Y}_{2},..., \textrm{Y}_{k}]=[\textit{g}_{2}|\textrm{Y}]$

> 1. My problem :: I am trying to understand how $\textrm{(i)} \Longrightarrow \textrm{(ii)}$.

The definition of [tower rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation) is

For sub-$\sigma$ algebras, $\mathcal{H}_{1}\subset \mathcal{H}_{2}\subset \mathscr{F}$, we have $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}[\mathit{X}|\mathcal{H}_{2}]|\mathcal{H}_{1}) \\ =\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}[\mathit{X}|\mathcal{H}_{1}]|\mathcal{H}_{2}) \\ =\mathbb{E}(\mathit{X}|\mathcal{H}_{1})$.

For random variables $\mathit{X, Y, Z}$, $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}[\mathit{X}|\mathit{Y,Z}]|\mathit{Y}) = \mathbb{E}(\mathit{X}|\mathit{Y})$, which is never equal to $\mathbb{E}(\mathit{X}|\mathit{Y}).\mathbb{E}(\mathit{Z}|\mathit{Y})$

Also, given that $$\textit{g}_{\textrm{k}}(\textrm{Y}_{1}, \textrm{Y}_{2},..., \textrm{Y}_{k})  =\textit{E}_{\ \textrm{F}}[\textit{g}(\textrm{Y}_{1}, \textrm{Y}_{2},..., \textrm{Y}_{m})|\textrm{Y}_{1}, \textrm{Y}_{2},..., \textrm{Y}_{k}]$$ and $$\textit{g}_{\textrm{k}}(\textrm{y}_{1}, \textrm{y}_{2},..., \textrm{y}_{k})  =\textit{E}_{\ \textrm{F}}\textit{g}[\textrm{y}_{1}, \textrm{y}_{2},..., \textrm{y}_{k},\textrm{Y}_{k+1},...,\textrm{Y}_{m}]$$, where $\textit{g}(.)$ is the kernel function of the expectation functional $\mathbb{E}_{\textit{F}}{\textit{g}(.)}$

> 2. My question : Can we say $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}\mathit{X|Y)Z|Y})=\mathbb{E}(\mathit{X|Y}).\mathbb{E}(\mathit{Z|Y})$? Also do $\mathit{X}$ and $\mathit{Z}$ need to be independent?

I am surely missing some fact to figure out how $\textrm{(i)} \Longrightarrow \textrm{(ii)}$ and my second question arises due to my problem. Also, gone through this [related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2962348/how-to-geometrically-interpret-conditional-expectation-property-tower-rule) still it is not clear how to overcome my problem. Therefore all comments, explanations, hints and answers are welcome and valuable.

> 3. Does there exist any generalized form or version of the tower property?

*Edit : I guess that the notion of conditional independence [$\mathbb{E}(\mathit{XY|Z})=\mathbb{E}(\mathit{X|Z}).\mathbb{E}(\mathit{Y|Z})$] is necessary to assume to determine the $\mathbb{E}(\mathit{XY})$ part and in that case the proof becomes easier.

Comment: Can you rewrite this in a readable format? For example, it seems to me that (i) does not imply (ii) as written because (i) is an expectation (a real number) while (ii) is a conditional expectation (which is a random variable). So, you probably copy the result wrong.

Comment: I am copying it from an online note on large sample theory. I am checking if I copied anything wrong. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I think (i) is not a real number. as it is not of the form $\mathbb{E}(\mathit{(XY|Z=z)}$. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I check the notes. The notes are correct, what you wrote isn't (in(ii) you are missing an expectation, you should have $E(E(...)E(...))$ and not $E(...)E(...)$).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $Y^k = (Y_1, \ldots, Y_k),$ and $A = (Y_{k + 1}, \ldots, Y_m)$ and $B = (Y_{m+1}, \ldots, Y_{m+s})$ (with $s = m-k$ say). You have $E(u(Y^k, A)v(Y^k, B))$ for a pair of functions $u$ and $v.$ Since $A$ and $B$ are independent, we can see that
$$
\begin{align*}
E(u(Y^k, A) v(Y^k, B)) &= E(E(u(Y^k, A)v(Y^k, B)\mid Y^k)) \\
&= E(E(u(Y^k, A) \mid Y^k)E(v(Y^k, B)\mid Y^k)).
\end{align*}
$$
(This is so since given $Y^k,$ the random variables $u(Y^k, A)$ and $v(Y^k, B)$ depend solely on independent random variables, viz. $A$ and $B$.)

Comment: +1 for the fantastic answer. 

I guess $Y^k$ is only known part here and that's why u and v solely depend on it.

Comment: Note you need $A, B, Y^k$ to be mutually independent, not just $A,B$.

Comment: For independent Bernoulli $X_1, X_2$ (with $p=1/2$) define $A = (-1)^{X_1}, B = (-1)^{X_2}$ and $Y^k = AB$.  Then define $u(x,y) = y$ and $v(x,y) = xy$.  Your equation becomes $1=0$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring thank you so much, I guess I am dusty somewhat in conditional expectation.

Comment: @BrianMoehring, I want to understand how do you plug-in $A$ and $B$ into $u(x,y)=y$ or $v(x,y)=xy$. Thank you for the valuable examples.

Comment: @vbm The same way you would if they were plain real numbers: $u(Y^k,A)=A$ and $v(Y^k,B)=Y^kB=A$.